# need to get everything after 2nd dash in string?

Tags: c#, regex

I have string values like those below:

```
string str1 = "123-456-test";
string str1 = "123 - 456 - test-test";
string str1 = "123-REQ456-test";
string str1 = "123 - REQ456 - test-test";
```

I need to grab the entire content from string right after the 2nd dash.

I tried `String.Split('-')`, but it did not work. I think I need to use a regex, but I am not able to find a correct one. Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?:[^-\n]+-){2}(.*)$
```

You can try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tS1hW2/21

Answer (score 5):

This even easy with string methods like [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [`Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
string str1 = "123-456-test";
int secondIndex = str1.IndexOf('-', str1.IndexOf('-') + 1);
str1 = str1.Substring(secondIndex + 1); // test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ `Skip(2)` with `Split`, no need to use a regex in C# for this task:

```
string input = "123-456-test";
string res = input.Contains("-") && input.Split('-').GetLength(0) > 2 ? string.Join("-", input.Split('-').Skip(2).ToList()) : input;
```

Result:

[image]

In case you want to use a regex by all means, you can leverage a [variable-width look-behind in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookbehind_assertion):

```
(?<=(?:-[^-]*){2}).+$
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D(%3F%3A-%5B%5E-%5Cn%5D*)%7B2%7D).%2B%24&i=123-456-test%0D%0A123%20-%20456%20-%20test-test%0D%0A123-REQ456-test%0D%0A123%20-%20REQ456%20-%20test-test&o=m)

Sample code:

```
var rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=(?:-[^-]*){2}).+$");
Console.WriteLine(rgx.Match("123-456-test").Value);
Console.WriteLine(rgx.Match("123 - 456 - test-test").Value);
Console.WriteLine(rgx.Match("123-REQ456-test").Value);
Console.WriteLine(rgx.Match("123 - REQ456 - test-test").Value);
```

Output:

```
test
 test-test
test
 test-test
```

Comment: I think using `Split` is something you could explore further, but a mere `String.IndexOf` should be most efficient (see Soner's answer).