# RegEx Match anything after second dash occurrence

Tags: c#, .net, regex, match, regex-group

Having the following string samples

```
"01:23:45 - site name1 - message received1"
"01:23:45 - site name2 - message received2"
"01:23:45 - site name3 - message received3"
"01:23:45 - site name4 - message received4"
```

I'm expecting to get:

```
"message received1"
"message received2"
"message received3"
"message received4"
```

and actually i got this result by using [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7K6Z4m)

```
string pattern = @"(?:[^-\n]+-){2}(.*)$";
string input = @"
01:21:42 - site name1 - message received1
02:22:43 - site name2 - message received2
03:23:44 - site name3 - message received3
04:24:45 - site name4 - message received4";

RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
{
 Console.WriteLine("{0}", m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

but only as a `Group[1]` of matches since in `Group[0]` i've got a full match of every line. So the question is, is there any way to get this result without having to deal with the Groups? Is there any perfomance issue related to use of multiple groups?

Comment: You are using two group, a non-capturing one `(?:[^-\n]+-)` and a capturing one `(.*)`. Could you check the `Group[0]` and `Group[1]` and looks at its `.Captures` property? Check the first code sample in [Match.Groups documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30501096/3832970 showing how it is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET supports using a quantifier `{2}` in the lookbehind`(?<=`

You could omit the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` as the pattern does not match only lowercase characters.

You could change the pattern to gettin only the `m.Value`

```
 (?<=(?:[^-\n]+-){2}).+$
```

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%28%3f%3a%5b%5e-%5cn%5d%2b-%29%7b2%7d%29.%2b%24&i=01%3a23%3a45+-+site+name1+-+message+received1%0d%0a01%3a23%3a45+-+site+name2+-+message+received2%0d%0a01%3a23%3a45+-+site+name3+-+message+received3%0d%0a01%3a23%3a45+-+site+name4+-+message+received4%22&o=m)

For example

```
string pattern = @"(?<=(?:[^-\n]+-){2}).+$";
string input = @"
01:21:42 - site name1 - message received1
02:22:43 - site name2 - message received2
03:23:44 - site name3 - message received3
04:24:45 - site name4 - message received4";

RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", m.Value);
}
```

Output

```
 message received1
 message received2
 message received3
 message received4
```

Comment: this worked like a charm! I was testing my regex with regex101.com which doesn't support .Net. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach without Regex

```c
string input = @"
   01:21:42 - site name1 - message received1
   02:22:43 - site name2 - message received2
   03:23:44 - site name3 - message received3
   04:24:45 - site name4 - message received4";

var messages = input
  .Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Select(line => line.Split('-').Last().Trim())
  .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, messages));
```

Output

```
message received1
message received2
message received3
message received4
```